# AVL tree delete

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

> Find an example AVL tree such that removing a single (specific) value
> from the tree causes rebalancing to occur starting at two different
> nodes.

I have this as my homework question. I know what an AVL tree is, but I don't understand the above question. Can someone shed some light?

Does rebalancing at two different nodes mean that two rotations are needed to fix the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AVL rebalance operation is a time when a particular node needs to have either a single or double rotation applied to correct the imbalance in the tree.  I think the question is asking you to find a case where doing a single or double rotation within an AVL tree locally fixes the balance, but then requires a rebalance operation to be performed at a node higher up in the tree.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah well...i think for avl trees, at most only 2 operations/rotations are needed to balance the tree..right? So if i perform two rotations..then my tree should be balanced...so a rebalance operation wouldn't be needed higher up in the tree...right? So i don't the answer you suggested does justice to this question.

Comment: @Nikhil- My intent was just to clarify what the assignment says.  It is not necessarily true that two rotations will suffice, and your homework is to figure out why.

Comment: oh yea...in case of insertions, at most a double rotation can balance the tree. But in case of deletion, the imbalance can propagate upward ... my bad....I'll dig more into this..

Comment: Hi...I just wrote a solution to the above problem and uploaded a pic here.. can you tell me if this if right?

http://picpaste.com/2013-03-20_07-09-09_14-ig4xR7Oq.jpg

With respect to above picture :
1)Delete node 79
2)1st rotation -->Left rotate 76
3)2nd rotation -->right rotate 78

Comment: And i found another example here :

https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs240/s10/handouts/tree-examples.pdf

In the above pdf ...the example to delete(22);I think that answers the above question..what do you think?