# AVL Tree deletion on a specific condition when the node to be rotated has a child

Tags: data-structures

I have read multiple questions about AVL tree deletion. But i lack to gather two below information:

1. Whats the algorithm that works when we have right, or left child to the node being deleted. And also when the node is deleted and some node is changed because of rotation and that node has left / right child. In this case what will happen to the node (to be rotated) left and right child
2. Is there a formula to keep in mind when we have left heavy or right heavy situation. (Many comments suggest that if left subtree is heavy, the right subtree balancing factor has to be taken into account and viceversa). But practically in either case the corresponding subtree is not impacted, then how its balancing factor be it - -1,0,1 mattters

The above two questions have not been present in the similar posts

Here are few scenarios where the implementation as mentioned above fails.

a. When the node is being deleted or impacted because of the rotation has one or more childs - i,e case where the node due to rotation has to change its place and has multiple other children
Like it is in the picture attached and scenario where node 44 has to be deleted

b. In many cases where irrespective of un-impacted subtree balanace factor both LL or LR and RR or RL rotations balance the tree. So no fixed formula which can be applied. (When 44 has to be deleted how right subtree balancing factor matters.

Any help on above would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AVL tree delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484287/avl-tree-delete)

Comment: What happens if after deletion the node which is rotated has left or right chlid. For example if node z is deleted which is causing rotation on node n and node n has l child. Post rotation node n has to go to right subtree, how will l child be placed. Will it not be a new insertion of child l – This is left unanswered yet

Answer (score 0):

When a node `Z` is about to be deleted, heights of the subtrees containing `Z` may be changed. For that reason, rebalancing has to be performed of all nodes from the deleted one until the root.

Deleting `Z` if both children are null is removing it and checking all parents for balances.

If some of the `Z`’s children is not null, then deleting means it's being replaced with the predecessor or successor node `N` (which is not necessarily the `Z`'s child, and `N` has at most one child). `N`’s parent `A` takes `N`’s single child `B` as a new child instead of `N` , `Z` is replaced with `N`.

Nodes starting from `A` should be checked for balances and rotated if necessary in the manner similar to node inserting. If `A`’s height has not changed (balance is 0), the deleting procedure ends; otherwise, `A` becomes `A`’s parent and the procedure is repeated. These are the cases for deleting (`b` is the node's balance value, `r` is the right rotation and `l` is the left rotation of a node):

1. `b(A) = 0`, after deleting `b(A) =±1` and height of `A`-tree is not changed, so the deleting procedure ends.
2. `b(A) =±1`, after deleting `b(A) = 0`, so there’s no need for rotations; but the height of trees containing `A` has changed, so the procedure of balancing continues on parent of `A`.
3. `b(A) =±1`, after deleting `b(A) =±2`, so the rotations are made; the height of trees containing `A` is changed, so the procedure of balancing continues on the parent of `A`.
4. `b(A) =−2, b(B) = 0:` perform `r(A)` which sets `b(A) =−1, b(B) = +1`; the deletion procedure ends.
5. `b(A) = +2, b(B) = 0:` perform `l(A)` which sets `b(A) = +1, b(B) =−1`; the deletion procedure ends.

Comment: What happens if after deletion the node which is rotated has left or right chlid. For example if node z is deleted which is causing rotation on node n and node n has l child. Post rotation node n has to go to right subtree, how will l child be placed. Will it not be a new insertion of child l

Comment: If the deleted node Z has a child, then it is replaced by it's successor N as described above. The balancing procedure starts from N's parent A up to the root.

Comment: Sorry, n node is deleted. Understood the inorder predecessor or successor. My question is post delete of node n. Node P is right/left rotated to balance out, and if node P has left /right child. How will this condition be handled is an optimized way .